# Undefined owner in token balances structure even though there's an owner

Tags: spl-token, account, jsonrpc-api

When calling `getParsedTransaction`, in the `tokenBalances` [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#token-balances-structure) I get an undefined owner even though the token account has an owner?

**Here is example**

getting the transaction info for `4XiDd3MBPd3cfNacyxCecx5SaJu6KNCtzUQcQSVqYM3bsMHvGYaM65iZ34RLaAsQXCVzzH7C2Wftnbv1dXM1WuKY`

in `postTokenBalances` I get

```
accountIndex: 2
mint: "Ar3T1wiyJREhuRVb4FdXCuEFCZECGpfhUCYiZT4Hv2GT"
owner: undefined
```

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer?

Comment: I did not find an answer sadly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those fields were not present in the tokenBalances maps when we started saving that metadata into the foundation BigTable storage.
The change that started storing the `owner` field [landed in master on October 13, 2021](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/20642), and the change that started storing the `programId` field [landed on master on April 20, 2022](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/24513). In both cases, it would have taken some additional time for those features to be rolled out on mainnet-beta.

Your example transaction was processed Sept 27, 2021, before both changes.

Comment: This would be an awesome addition to the docs. Want to send a PR, @vicyyn? :)

Comment: Definitely! Will do.